# Receiving a big file from socket floods memory, do I have a memory leak?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I want to send a big file from one machine to another. All bytes are sent succesfully, and they are also received on the other end, but the operation massively hits the memory on the receiving end. Memory usage goes up at about 400MB per second for a few seconds, then settles back down. The file I tested with is about 7 gigs in size.

This is the code I use to read from the socket into the file:

```
size_t recv_file(int socket, std::filesystem::path& dest_file) {
    uint64_t bytes_to_read = recv_byte_count(socket);
    char* const file_buffer = new char[MAX_BUFFER_FILE];
    size_t total_received{ 0 };

    try {
        std::fstream fs;
        fs.open(dest_file, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

        while (bytes_to_read > 0) {
            const unsigned int actual_bytes_to_read = (bytes_to_read > MAX_BUFFER_FILE) ? MAX_BUFFER_FILE : bytes_to_read;

            size_t received = recv_raw(socket, file_buffer, actual_bytes_to_read, MAX_BUFFER_FILE);

            if (received > 0) {
                fs.write(file_buffer, received);
                bytes_to_read -= received;
                total_received += received;
                std::cout << "Bytes received: " << total_received << std::endl;
                memset(file_buffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER_FILE);


            } else throw WSA_socket_exception(WSAGetLastError(), socket);

        }

        fs.close();
        delete[] file_buffer;
    }
    catch (...) {
        delete[] file_buffer;
        return 0;
    }
    return total_received;
}


size_t recv_raw(const int socket, void* buffer, size_t bytes_to_read, int buffer_size = MAX_BUFFER) {
    char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
    size_t received_total{ 0 };

    while (bytes_to_read > 0) {
        const int actual_bytes_to_read{ std::min(buffer_size, static_cast<int>(bytes_to_read)) };

        const int received = recv(socket, ptr, actual_bytes_to_read, 0);
        if (received == 0 || received < -1) throw connection_close_exception(socket);
        if (received > 0) {
            bytes_to_read -= static_cast<size_t>(received);
            ptr += received;
            received_total += static_cast<size_t>(received);
        }
    }
    return received_total;
}
```

Comment: You are using std::endl in your example, that could have some synchronisation side effects, is the problem the same with and without it?

Comment: While this has unfortunately not helped, I would like to understand why this could have helped

Comment: As standard std::endl flushes the std::cout blocking this thread until its done, this could mean that the tcp adds more data buffers while this happens. It could cause a process switch, it might need to sync with stdio if not using std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data gets copied many times during the process from receiving until its finally written to the file.

Both tcp and file might allocate many temporary buffers waiting for either received to be called or the file to be (partial) flushed to the file system. Tcp is controlled by your tcp settings defining how much it can allocate, there might be a similar setting in fs, else you can roll your own by rolling your own sub class of std::streambuf.

Comment: None of that should allocate 400MB though.